# git bash for windows with empty prompt

Tags: windows, git-bash

I was using Git for Windows there is a long time, but these days I've been in troubles with it. Suddenly it stopped working. I've been trying to unninstall and reinstall it many times, but even the uninss000.exe doesn't work as well. Look at the picture and it stands like this forever.

Have anyone had this problem? How can I solve it? I've been looking for it and I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance,

[image: When I try to load git, it's what happen]

Comment: Did you try to unzip a portable version of Git for Windows, and launch a `git-bash.bat`?: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.2-preview20140411/PortableGit-1.9.2-preview20140411.7z. Try turning you anti-virus (briefly) off to see of there is a side-effect.

Comment: The portable version works as the same as above. It's weird because after launching git-bash.bat or sh, I can't close it. I will try with the anti-virus off.

Comment: With the antivirus off the only difference is that I can easily close the bash, but nothing happens.

Comment: Ok. On which windows are you? W8 64bits?

Comment: W7 64bits. I will try now SourceTree for windows

Comment: I formatted it and now its working =)

Comment: @Renan: I have the same problem. When you say format, did you mean format the hard drive?

Comment: @RenanBandeira:  I have the same problem. When you say format, did you mean format the hard drive? –

Comment: @user227710 yap I did! :/